# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sense'

Tags: python

```
landmarks = [[20.0,20.0],[80.0,80.0],[20.0,80.0],[80.0,20.0]]
world_size = 20.0

class robot:
   def __init__(self):
      self.x=random.random()*world_size
      self.y=random.random()*world_size
      self.orientation=random.random()*2.0*pi
      self.forward_noise= 0.0
      self.turn_noise=0.0
      self.sense_noise=0.0

  def set(self,new_x,new_y,new_orientation):
      self.x= float(new_x)
      self.y= float(new_y)
      self.orientaion=float(new_orientation)

  def move(self,turn,distance_move):
      self.orientation += turn%(2*pi)
      self.x += distance_move*(cos(self.orientaion))
      self.y += distance_move*(sin(self.orientaion))

  def sense(self):
     z=[]
     for i in range(len(landmarks)):
         x = sqrt((self.x - landmarks[i][0])**2 + (self.y-landmarks[i][1])**2)
         z.append(x)
         return z

myrobot= robot() 
myrobot.set(30.0,50.0,pi/2)
myrobot=myrobot.move((-pi)/2,15.0)
print(myrobot.sense())  
myrobot=myrobot.move((-pi)/2,10.0)
print(myrobot.sense())
```

i am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/particle robot.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(myrobot.sense())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sense'.
```

What is the problem with the code

Comment: You're reassigning `myrobot` to be the result of calling `myrobot.move()`.  What does `myrobot.move()` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You replaced your `myrobot` variable with the return value of the `robot.move()` method:

```
myrobot=myrobot.move((-pi)/2,10.0)
```

Because `myrobot.move()` returns `None` (the default if there is no `return` statement in a function), your next line breaks.

Don't assign the return value, only call `move()`:

```
myrobot.move((-pi)/2,10.0)
```

Comment: Or, make sure that `myrobot.move(...)` returns itself.

Comment: @BryanOakley: it modifies the position in-place; the convention is to return `None` in that case.

Comment: True, but in some types of applications (and working with robots seems like one) it's convenient to be able to do something like `myrobot.move(...).sense(...).move(...)`. Admittedly, it's hard to tell what the OP was hoping to accomplish with `myrobot = myrobot.move(...)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley: yup, sometimes chaining is helpful, but they are not nearly as common, and often you get a new instance back anyway (e.g. SQLAlchemy).